# Retornando o valor de um ponteiro

Tags: c

#### Preciso criar uma função que tenha o funcionamento idêntico à função `strcat`. A princípio me parecia uma tarefa bastante simples, porém quando printo o retorno da função `ft_strcat()` isto acontece:

#### Sendo `pont = dest` então por que retornam coisas diferentes?

- Definição da função:

```
char *ft_strcat(char *dest, char *src) {
    char *pont;

    pont = dest;

    for(; *dest; dest++){
    }
    for(; *src; ){
        *dest++ = *src++;
    }
    *dest = '\0';
    return dest; /* return pont */
}
```

- Resultado 1 (Retornando `dest`):

> `cd "/mnt/c/Users/ex02/" && gcc ft_strcat.c -o ft_strcat && "/mnt/c/Users/ex02/"ft_strcat`

- Resultado 2, (Retornando `pont`):

> - Resultado: `cd "/mnt/c/Users/ex02/" && gcc ft_strcat.c -o ft_strcat && "/mnt/c/Users/ex02/"ft_strcat`
>   `hello world%`

---

##### Código completo caso necessário:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
char *ft_strcat(char *dest, char *src);

int main(void){
    char texto[20] = {"hello"};
    char fonte[20] = {" world"};
    
    printf("%s", ft_strcat(texto, fonte));

    return 0;
}

char *ft_strcat(char *dest, char *src) {
    char *pont;

    pont = dest;

    for(; *dest; dest++){
    }
    for(; *src; ){
        *dest++ = *src++;
    }
    *dest = '\0';
    return dest;
}
```

Comment: Bom, `pont` certamente é diferente de `dest` já que você incrementou `dest` várias vezes. Agora `dest` aponta simplesmente para um EOF, enquanto que `pont` ainda tem a referência original ao começo da string. Cuidado, essa função não está levando em conta a quantidade de memória alocada. Se a frase inteira tiver mais caracteres do que a quantidade alocada para a string destino, vai dar problema.

Comment: Percebo, mas no caso de eu querer printar a string completa de `dest`, sem ter que atribuir um `pont` = `dest`, como eu deveria prosseguir? Obrigado

Comment: Uma maneira seria manter um registro de quantas vezes `dest` foi incrementado e decrementá-lo de volta ao começo. Mas do jeito que está, é o mais natural mesmo.

Comment: Era só fazer `return pont;` e pronto. Ao fazer `pont = dest;` no início, `pont` recebe o valor que `dest` tinha naquele momento (que era um ponteiro para o início da string). Depois vc incrementa `dest`, mas isso não altera `pont` (ela ainda aponta para o início da string, por isso basta retorná-lo que funciona, veja: https://ideone.com/OHUdUR). A resposta abaixo faz um malabarismo desnecessário: `(dest - (dest - pont))` não faz o menor sentido e aceitar essa resposta é um desserviço ao site, pois muita gente pode ver o aceite e achar que aquilo está certo.

Comment: Aproveitando, acho que vale a pena ler [isso](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2001/12/11/back-to-basics/) - o artigo é longo, mas tem uma parte interessante sobre `strcat`

Comment: E só pra deixar claro, a expressão `(dest - (dest - pont))` é equivalente a `pont` (matemática básica, de forma geral, `(x - (x - y))` sempre será igual a `y`), por isso que no fim "funciona". Mas pra que essa complicação desnecessária? Simplesmente retorne o `pont` e pronto.

Comment: Se você ler bem o código vai ver que há um comentário no retorno da função `return pont;`. Já consegui perceber onde estava a minha dúvida. Eu acreditava que após usar aritimética de ponteiros, o mesmo ponteiro sempre retornava apontado para o primeiro elemento do array.

Comment: Sim, eu  já tinha visto, e isso não muda nada minha explicação... Os dois começam apontando pro mesmo lugar, e depois vc incrementa apenas um deles (`dest`), mas o outro (`pont`) não é modificado

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Quando você retorna dest... vc retorna pro terminal a ultima posição de dest(isso acontece porque vc incrementou ele ao longo da função); no seu caso a ultima posição dele é o '\0'. por isso não mostra nada.

pont retorna corretamente pq n usou ele pra andar posições na string, ele apenas recebeu tudo de dest.

Sua string no final seria "hello world\0" tendo 11 posições aí.

quando vc retorna dest ele retorna a posição 11 da string. pra resolver isso vc teria q retornar dest pro inicio da string..

```
char *ft_strcat(char *dest, char *src) {
char *pont;

pont = dest;

for(; *dest; dest++){
}
for(; *src; ){
    *dest++ = *src++;
}
*dest = '\0';
return (dest - (dest - pont)); // aqui seria dessa forma...  dest vale 11 e pont 0 logo no retorno ta acontecendo. 11 - (11 - 0) 11 - 11 da 0.. assim seu dest  volta pro inicio e o resultado mostra na tela
```

}

[A imagem abaixo mostra uma representação visual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lnui0.png)

Comment: Não precisa de nada disso, pois `pont` já aponta pro início da string, então bastaria fazer `return pont`

Comment: Aliás, `(dest - (dest - pont))` é equivalente a  `pont` (matemática básica, por exemplo, `(5 - (5 - 2))` é igual a 2 - basicamente `(x - (x - y))` é igual a `y`, por isso que "funciona". Mas ainda sim, pra que complicar? Retorne simplesmente `pont` e pronto

Comment: Obrigado Jonatas.

Comment: Aprecio o seu esforço em criar a imagem. Realmente bastante ilustrativa. Obrigado

Comment: @hkotsubo Sei disso, e concordo com vc, no entanto ele queria entender pq ambos se comportavam de forma diferente, entao apenas expliquei e  mostrei q se ele quiser usar o dest teria q usar daquela forma...

Comment: "*se ele quiser usar o dest*" - Se `dest` aponta pro que ele não precisa, e `pont` aponta pro que ele precisa, então é pra usar  somente `pont`, e não `dest`, simples assim. Não tem essa de "querer", se eu quero usar o ponteiro errado em vez do certo, então estará errado de qualquer jeito (mesmo que "funcione")